# How to create a trigger to bring a date column and a time column together?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I need to populate a DATETIME column with the data from other columns, one for the date and one for the time.

This is part of a code I've written but I am stuck at actually combining them:

THANK YOU!
delimiter $

create trigger fulldate

```
before insert 



on Tabela_veche 



for each row
```

begin

```
if new.fulldate is null then



    set new.fulldate = = CONCAT();



end if;
```

end $

Comment: Are the date and time columns date and time datatypes or char datatypes?

Comment: Also most likely a [Generated Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) is more easy..

Comment: I created them as Date and Time and the fulldate column as datetime.
I must do this with the trigger as after this command I will import the txt file with all the actual data.

Comment: I tried this: set new.fulldate = CONCAT('data_achizitie', 'ora_achizitie');
however, I get an error when I try to load the txt file saying that the fulldate has an incorrect value as datetime

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table looks a bit like this

```
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+---------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra   |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+---------+
| dt       | date     | YES  |     | NULL    |         |
| tm       | time     | YES  |     | NULL    |         |
| fulldttm | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |         |
| gcdttm   | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    | VIRTUAL |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

and dt is formatted '2019-01-01' and time '10:00:00' then str_to_date

select str_to_date(concat(dt,' ',tm),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') dttm
from t;
```

returns

```
+---------------------+
| dttm                |
+---------------------+
| 2019-00-01 10:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As pointed out by @Raymond Nijland you may be able to use a generated column

```
`gcdttm` datetime AS (str_to_date(concat(dt,' ',tm) ,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s'))
```

and not bother with the trigger at all.

```
+------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| dt         | tm       | fulldttm | gcdttm              |
+------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 2019-01-01 | 10:00:00 | NULL     | 2019-00-01 10:00:00 |
+------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```